# SQL-Statement: Show all users who are enrolled in a moodle course

Tags: moodle-api

i search an sql-statement which gives all users, who are enrolled in a Moodle_course,
example course_id = 50?

Who can help?

Thanks a lot?

PS: Is there an API from webservice? If Yes, how can i use the API?
My goal is to be able to process the XML result, which i get via rest-API from "core_enrol_get_enrolled_users" further with PHP.

Thanks a lot

D-T

Answer (score 0):

Here are to SQL-Statements which works...

First, shows the users for every course

```
SELECT distinct 

u.lastname AS Nachname,

u.firstname AS Vorname, 

c.fullname AS Kursname



FROM 

(((mdl_user AS u INNER JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS user_enr ON u.id = user_enr.userid)

INNER JOIN mdl_enrol AS enr ON user_enr.enrolid = enr.id) 

INNER JOIN mdl_course AS c ON enr.courseid = 638) 

INNER JOIN mdl_course_completions AS course_compl ON (user_enr.userid = course_compl.userid) 

WHERE u.deleted=0
```

### Last: Show the user vor a special Course (here 111)

```
SELECT username, idnumber,
firstname, lastname, email
FROM mdl_user_enrolments ue
JOIN mdl_enrol en ON ue.enrolid = en.id
JOIN mdl_user uu ON uu.id = ue.userid 
WHERE en.courseid = 111
```